# How do you read cell values from a Google Drive Spreadsheet?

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I want to read some simple parameters from a Google Drive Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script API and then return that value as part of the doPost() response in the GAS script to a javascript function I call from my local website.

I know how to write to a Speadsheet

```
function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName('RequestInvites').appendRow([e.parameter.emailAddress, 'hash123']);

  app.add(app.createLabel("Form submitted. Your email address is: '" + e.parameter.emailAddress));

  return app;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to read a value from a Spreadsheet and return a response to the calling script on my site (using jQuery's `$.ajax()` function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range.getValue() ?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#getValue

To return a value. I suspect HTML service is the cleanest way. Although I came across a post showing how do it with by throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to directly send a response as explained here:

[Using ContentService with doPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935420/how-to-use-contentservice-and-dopost-to-create-a-rest-api)

ContentService will work if you make a second call to a doGet. The problem is it is challenging to connect the output to what was sent in the doPost.